# React native carousel item active index

Tags: react-native, carousel, splash-screen

I've just started learning react native and I want to make a splash screen that contains a slider with dots. But when I scroll the scrollview the active dot doesn't change properly. My slider component is like below

```
export default function Slider() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

  const onChange = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const active = Math.floor(
      nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width
    );

    setActive({ active });

    console.log(active);
   
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        onMomentumScrollEnd={onChange}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        {dummyData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <SliderItem
              key={index}
              title={item.title}
              image={item.url}
              description={item.description}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.dotView}>
        {dummyData.map((k, i) => (
          <View
            key={i}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: i === active ? "red" : "blue", // My problem is here
              height: 10,

              width: 10,

              margin: 8,
              borderRadius: 6,
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `setActive({ active });` to `setActive(active);`

Comment: Thanks,it's working. What is the reason behind that ? can you explain a little bit

Comment: I'm glad it helped. There is not much to explain actually, 'setActive' is a function that updates the 'active' state according to what it receives. that's how it works with 'useState' setters. Calling 'setActive' the way you did is only relevant if 'active' was an object with field called active but since it's a number you should send it without the curly braces.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer helped me a lot.